# Permutation and combination with overcounting

Tags: permutations, combinations

A lady gives a dinner party to six quests. The number of ways in which they may be selected from among ten friends, if two of the friends will not attend the party together is 
(a) $112$     (b) $140$ 
(c) $164$      (d) None of these

***what i tried:***
 Since two friend will not attend party together i considered them as one, so now there 9 friends.
So the number of ways $6$ people are selected from $9$ people=$\frac{9\times8\times7\times6\times5\times4}{6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1}$=$84$

So the number of ways $6$ people are selected from $9$ people=**$84$**

but we have considered two people as one because either will be attending party 

So the actual number of arrangements with two friends not attending party together=$84$$\times$$2$=$168$
So is the Answer $168$ i.e None of these

Comment: This doesn't work because you are double counting the arrangements where neither of the rivals was in the group of 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, for the arrangements that do not include the rival, you should see how many parties you can invite from the 8 remaining.

Then you need to see how many ways you can match up Rival #1 with 5 people from the remaining 8.  Then how many ways can you match up Rival #2 with 5 people from the remaining 8.

ETA: Probably easier method would be ${10\choose 6}-{8\choose 4}$ which is total parties of 6 minus parties containing both rivals.

Comment: So according to your suggestion if do $C^8_5$*2. I get 112 as my answer is this right

Comment: To 112 you have to add in the number of parties that do not include any of the rivals.

Comment: iam confused can you please help me with it

Comment: You got the 112 part right.  But those are only the two ways you can choose 5 people to go with a rival.  To that you have to add the number of groups of 6 you can choose from 8.  Which is $C^8_6$.  Because the group of 6 doesn't necessarily have to include those two people who can't get along.

Comment: so the answer is $C^8_5$*$2$$+$$C^8_6$=$140$

Comment: And you can check your answer by computing the total number of parties ,$10\choose 6$, minus the number of parties with both rivals ,$8\choose 4$.

Answer (score -3):

If neither of the two unamicable friends don't attend the party, we choose $\binom{8}{6} = 28$.

Now if either of them is selected for the party (but not the other), we have $ \binom{2}{1}\cdot \binom{8}{5} = 112$.

Thus the answer will be $112+28= 140$.

Comment: Although a bit hard to read, this does provide an answer to the problem, $140$, argued by breaking the problem into two cases.